# Is it possible to remove subject relative pronouns? How?

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis

Consider the following sentences.

> Al Pacino is a famous actor **[who]** played Michel Corleone in The Godfather movie.
>
> Samsung is a very big company **[which]** produces home appliances.

Question: is it possible to remove subject relative pronouns (who/which)? If so, how?

Comment: You can use verb-*ing* (aka participles), e.g. *a famous actor, ruling the ...*, *a very big company, producing ...*.

Comment: No.  In Standard English you may not omit relative pronouns when the gap is in subject position.